# Reusable Types (Interfaces) in angular 8

Tags: angular6, angular7, angular8, typescript-typings

I am trying to create reusable interface which can be used for object of same type.
like UserDetails , in declaration.d.ts

```
declare module DataModel {
    interface UserDetails {
        userName: string;
        userId: number;
    }
}
```

So I tried to create one module with name DataModel which will have multiple objects type.

In my component I have created new variable as,

```
public userDetails: DataModel.UserDetails;
```

Note: I have imported DataModel.

In ngOnInit() I am trying to set values for userDetails,

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.userDetails.userName = "Guest";
  }
```

but when code runs I am getting below error,

Cannot set property 'userName' of undefined on variable userDetails.

I have tried to add 'declaration.d.ts' file in tsconfig.json in type array as well but its not working.

any workaround is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration is good, but you forgot to initialize your variable, so when you use it it's `undefined`.

I would recommand to initialize it as `null`, then do the assignation :

```
public userDetails: DataModel.UserDetails = null;


ngOnInit() {
   this.userDetails = {
       userName: 'Guest',
       userId: 0,
   };
}
```

Note that youn have to provide an `userId` or Typescript will tell you that `userId` is not defined as you do your assignation.

If you don't want to specify the `userId`, declare your interface as :

```
declare module DataModel {
    interface UserDetails {
        userName: string;
        userId?: number;
    }
}
```

Or type your attribute as :

```
public userDetails: Partial<DataModel.UserDetails>;
```

Which will allow every key of UserDetails to be optional

---

**Alternative**

You can initialize your data like :

```
public userDetails: DataModel.UserDetails = {
   userName: null,
   userId: 0,
};
```

Then use it as :

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.userDetails.userName = 'Guest';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gregory NEUT for this alternative.